# Will $Ax=b$ have a solution over $\Bbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{m\times n}$ be a matrix over $\Bbb Z$; $b$ is an $m\times 1$ vector over $\Bbb Z$

> 1.If $Ax=b$ has a solution over $\Bbb Z_p$ for some prime $p$ ,will 
>   $Ax=b$  have  a solution over $\Bbb R$?
>
> 2.If $Ax=b$ has a solution over $\Bbb Z_p$ for every prime $p$ ,will 
>   $Ax=b$  have  a solution over $\Bbb R$?

The answer to the first question is NO as $0x=3$ has a solution in $\Bbb Z_3$ but no solution in $\Bbb R$

However I am stuck on the second one .How should I prove /disprove the statement.Please give some hints.

Comment: May help: $A$ is invertible iff $\det A$ is invertible.

Comment: I don't know how would that hep@YoTengoUnLCD

Answer (score 0):

Idea: if $\det B\ne 0$ mod $p$ for $p$ large enough, then $\det B\ne 0$ in $\Bbb Z$. Apply this to some submatrix of $A$.

Comment: I am finding it tough to get an idea from your *IDEA*

Comment: @learnmore, start supposing that $A$ is a square matrix.

Answer (score 0):

A variant (perhaps?) hint to that of Martin-Blas's - think Gaussian elimination / row reduced echelon form.   Finding a solution over the reals is equivalent to finding one over the rationals. Gaussian elimination gives us an invertible matrix $R$, over a field $F$ (e.g., the rationals, or a finite field) so that $RA x = Rb$ has a solution over $F$ if and only if the non-zero entries of $Rb$ lie in rows with leading entry $1$ in $RA$.